# Get android screen resolution

Tags: c#, android, monogame

I need the code to get android screen resolution in API 10+

I am using monogame android

```
using Android.App;
_ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
```

This code only works in `Actvity1.cs` and not in `Game1.cs` , why is that ? I am `using Android.App;` statement...

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
        Game1.Activity = this;
        var g = new Game1();
        SetContentView(g.Window);
        g.Run();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED] try using this.

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int screen_width    = metrics.widthPixels;
int screen_height   = metrics.heightPixels;
float density       = metrics.density;
```

OR like this

```
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
public class Resolution()
{
int screen_width;
int screen_height;
float density;

public Resolution(Activity activity)
{
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    screen_width    = metrics.widthPixels;
    screen_height   = metrics.heightPixels;
    density         = metrics.density;
}
}
```

and in your activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Resolution res = new Resolution(this); //your activity in param
        int width = res.screen_width;
        int height = res.screen_height;

    }
}
```

Comment: please .. give me the using statement

Comment: where does DisplayMetrics belong ? what namespace ?

Comment: i use android.util.DisplayMetrics (if this is what you looking for)

Comment: what about getWindowManager() ? whats the namespace of that ?

Comment: it's a method of your activity

Comment: i cant call it outside activity ?

Comment: see my question i added some code, thats how my oncreate looks, iwant to know the screen resolution on Game1.cs not Activity1.cs

Comment: sorry i didn't pay attention that you use C# and monogame for your app, i thought that was for java and eclipse. sorry i don't have the answer, tried to help.

Comment: its exactly the same thing.. i just cant figure out how to pass that variable from activity1 to game1